# Two improper integrals (0 to infinity)

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals

Given is a function of $t$ (with parameter $u>0$):

$$
f(t,u)= \frac{1}{t+u}\ \exp \,\left\{ -\frac{(a-t)^2+b^2}{2(t+u)} - \frac{c^2}{2t}\right\}
$$

For the special case $u=0$, the following integral is solvable (with the abbreviation $r = \sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}$):

$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{dt}{\sqrt{t}} \, f(t,0)\, = \,  \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{r}\ e^{a-r}$$

Q1: Is there a solution for the general case $u>0$, i.e. for $\int_{0}^{\infty} t^{-1/2} f(t,u)\, dt$? (Even a yes/no answer would be of great help.)

Q2: If there is *no* solution, is there at least a solution for the case $c=0$?

Thanks in advance for the answer to this difficult question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the general case? $\int \frac{f(t,u)}{\sqrt{t}}$?

Comment: special case: $u=0$, general case: $u>0$ (the parameter u is a positive real number)